# Where to place authentication check in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, aop

I have some code used to determine if a user is logged in and I want to put this on every page in an ASP.NET website so that only logged in users can view it. The problem is that the site is split into multiple projects/solutions so maintaining the single piece of code might be hard.

I was thinking I could create a class that inherits for `System.Web.UI.Page` and overrides `Page_Init`, but that would require changing all pages so they inherit from new new class. Also I don't think this will work across projects.

So then I thought approaching the problem from a different side: using AOP. I have never used Aspects before but it looks like I could use PostSharp to write an Aspect that injects code before every `Page_Init` (or maybe `Page_Load`?). This might work as a quick solution but I might run into problems if I need a page to not perform the authentication check (available to everyone).

Just to clarify, I already have a login solution; I am just looking for a checking that login on each page.

Comment: Why aren't you using a [`MembershipProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx)? This all done for you by ASP.NET.

Comment: Generally ASP.NET pages should be built on a master page where common code is centralised, including login check. You could make 2 master pages, one that checks for it and one that does not.

Comment: @jrummell this is not flexible enough. In real life projects when going for customizable projects, one cannot go for MembershipProvider. Right?

Comment: @PankajGarg No, Membership is a flexible framework. You can implement your own provider if the built in ones don't meet your needs.

Comment: Membership is pretty flexible... Check CodeFirstMembershipProvider ;)

Answer (score 3):

Look into HttpModules. The asp.net framework is already programmed so that a module runs on every page request, you just have to write it and add it to web.config.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zec9k340(v=vs.71).aspx

EDIT: Here's a better link that demonstrates handling the BeginRequest event
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227673(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: No, the system will be flexible enough to write the code for the same in Code Behind, instead of mentioning the roles in web.config explicitly.

Comment: You don't specify the roles in the web.config, you just register the module. The workings of the authentication module are entirely up to you, web.config just says "run this module for each page request."

Answer (score 1):

As @jrummell mentioned, there's [`MembershipProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.aspx) which is a great option, but if you're creating custom login solition, check this [link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301240) which has a pretty simple login implementation step by step

Answer (score 1):

Since you seem to have your login solution handled and working, creating a class that overrides the page_init sounds like your best option. This can work across other projects by simply creating that class in a separate project that you can included in your other solution(s)... To be honest, that's the easiest way to span the logic across multiple projects.. This will also be easily maintained because you'd only have to update one location going forward.

If you are using MasterPages, you wouldn't have to hit all of the pages, you could just include it on specific MasterPage(s) and set all the pages you want authentication to use that MasterPage.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Identity Foundation can solve this for you. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/aa570351 for details on WIF. No need to reinvent the wheel. If you had only one Web application, Forms authentication would suffice.